# Optimize php mySQL query with mulitple joins and Group_Concat

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-concat

I have multiple join sets happening on my query. I have multiple joins, because of the way the tables are structured to get what I want. My main joins, I've separated into three sets as commented below. If I only have one set, the query time is pretty fast. When I have two sets active, the query time is around 2 minutes. If all three sets are active as shown below, it takes too long.

Any help on optimizing this query would be appreciated.

```
$query  = "SELECT   `Databases`.*, 
                    `DatabaseDescriptors`.*, 
                    `DatabaseContents`.*, 
                    `DatabaseAccessLevels`.*, 
                    `Providers`.*, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(`Descriptors`.DescriptorName SEPARATOR ', ') as DescriptorNames, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(`Contents`.ContentName SEPARATOR ', ') as ContentNames, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(`AccessLevels`.AccessLevelName SEPARATOR ', ') as AccessLevelNames ";

$query .= "FROM `Databases` ";

// SET 1

$query .= "JOIN `DatabaseDescriptors` 
                ON `DatabaseDescriptors`.DatabaseID = `Databases`.DatabaseID ";

$query .= "JOIN `Descriptors` 
                ON `Descriptors`.DescriptorID = `DatabaseDescriptors`.DescriptorID ";

//SET 2

$query .= "JOIN `DatabaseContents`
                ON `DatabaseContents`.DatabaseID = `Databases`.DatabaseID ";

$query .= "JOIN `Contents`
                ON `Contents`.ContentID = `DatabaseContents`.ContentID ";

//SET 3

$query .= "JOIN `DatabaseAccessLevels`
                ON `DatabaseAccessLevels`.DatabaseID = `Databases`.DatabaseID ";

$query .= "JOIN `AccessLevels`
                ON `AccessLevels`.AccessLevelID = `DatabaseAccessLevels`.AccessLevelID ";

$query .= "JOIN `Providers`
                ON `Providers`.ProviderID = `Databases`.ProviderID ";

$query .= "AND `Databases`.DatabaseID = 47";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the performance problem is that a "database" has multiple descriptors, access levels, and contents.  Say a database has 10 of each.  The query ends up turning this into 10*10*10 = 1000 rows for processing.

The solution is to do the aggregation before doing the join.  For instance, instead of this:
    $query .= "JOIN `DatabaseDescriptors` 
                    ON `DatabaseDescriptors`.DatabaseID = `Databases`.DatabaseID ";

```
$query .= "JOIN `Descriptors` 
                ON `Descriptors`.DescriptorID = `DatabaseDescriptors`.DescriptorID ";
```

You would have:

```
(select dd.DatabaseId,
         GROUP_CONCAT(d.DescriptorName SEPARATOR ', ') as DescriptorNames
 from DatabaseDescriptors dd join
      Descriptions d
      on dd.DescriptorID = d.DescriptorID
 group by dd.DatabaseId
) dd
on Databases.DatabaseId = dd.DatabaseId
```

(You can replace the `group by dd.DatabaseId` with `where dd.DatabaseId = 47` to just handle your one case.  My guess is that you might want this information for all databases.  If so, add a `group by DatabaseId` to the outer query.)

You then need to repeat this for all three of the `group_concat()` columns.

Note:  You are pulling all the fields from the all the tables.  However, only one row is returning because you have an aggregation query with no `group by`.  I'm guessing that you are also getting duplicates in the `group_concat()`-created lists.  This approach will also fix that problem.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. My limited knowledge in mySQL is not helping, but I understand what you mean. I'll try that approach.